# Program to determine when a disc (CD) has been written/burned

Tags: optical-media, forensics

I am looking for a program that can:

- determine the date and time when a disc has been written/burned

If possible:

- works on Windows 7
- free
- also works with DVDs

I am aware of [How to find out when a disc (DVD) has been written/burned?](https://superuser.com/a/559089/116475) but I would like to have a more convenient, faster method.